# Trouble installing whl (Images included)

Tags: python

[image]

I'm trying to install a .whl package on my 64bit Windows 10. 
I tried "pip install cx_Freeze", also tried the full directory name, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Run pip from `cmd` shell, not from inside of the python shell

Comment: printscreen is not the correct way to convey information important to your question, especially if it can appear as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to type in your command line  (not in your python console) :

```
python -m pip install yourwhladdress.whl
```

or

```
pip install yourwhladdress.whl
```